# Como encontrar o método mockito de acordo com o pacote?

Tags: java, maven

Estou tentando encontrar a biblioteca mockito de acordo com o pacote abaixo;

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
```

Já tentei essas bibliotecas jars, mas sem resultados;

- mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
- mockito-all-1.10.16.jar

Por favor, preciso saber qual é a biblioteca certa para encontrar esse método **any**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualquer Mockito com versão igual ou superior à 2.1.0 conforme descrito nas [release notes](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2):

> The Mockito class does not inherit from Matchers class anymore. Instead Mockito and Matchers classes both inherit from ArgumentMatchers. Also Matchers is now deprecated.